# Meteor checkbox group - At least one checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, checkbox, meteor, underscore.js

This is the checkboxes i have so far. 
I would like to have at least one checkbox checked all the time - how can this be accomplished?

**SOLUTION:**

```
HTML:

    <form>
        <ul>
            {{#each checkbox}}
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked"> {{name}}: {{checked}}
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </form>

JS:

    Cbtest = new Mongo.Collection('cbtest');

    Template.checkbox.helpers({
        checkbox: function () {
            return Cbtest.find();
        }
    });

    Template.checkbox.events({
        "click .toggle-checked": function (event) {
            var self = this;
            //deactivate the checkboxes visually
            event.preventDefault();
            Meteor.call("setChecked", self._id, !self.checked);
        }
    });

    Meteor.methods({
        setChecked: function (checkboxId, setChecked) {
            //deactivate the checkbox value change in the database
            if (!setChecked && CheckboxResources.find({
                checked: true
            }).count() === 1)
            return;
            Cbtest.update(checkboxId, {
                $set: {
                    checked: setChecked
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I'd like to avoid jquery and stick with javascript and underscorejs solely.

Thanks in advance!
Vin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make sure there are at least two checked items before updating the current item to `check: false`:

```
Meteor.methods({
    setChecked: function (checkboxId, setChecked) {
        if (!setChecked && Cbtest.find({checked: true}).count() === 1)
          return; // or throw error
        Cbtest.update(checkboxId, {
            $set: {
                checked: setChecked
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this works for the database values, but the last checkbox can still be unchecked - how can i prevent that?

Comment: Got it! Just added " event.preventDefault(); " to the Template.checkbox.events